# Edit button not showing in front end joomla template Skylab

Tags: button, joomla, frontend

Can anybody help me with getting the edit button in Joomla 2.5 front end showing. I am using template skylab.

Tried replacing files in com_content/article.
Can login with super user.
All acl are correct.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 'Major' reasons why this can occur

1. Upgrading Joomla Version (Sometimes Breaks Database)
2. Your template does not support front end editing, or is Broken.

Your template should contain or something similar.

```
user->authorize('com_content', 'publish', 'content', 'all')) : ?>
```

It is worth posting this question on the discussion forum on Joomla as they are normally as great as the people on here.

Comment: Thanx for answering. My template contains: 
<?php if ($this->user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id)) : ?>
<li class="edit-icon"><?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?></li><?php endif; ?>

I found a way around by making a user menu and putting articles in which are registered. That works but I do not know if this is right way! I found it on:

Comment: http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/06/joomla-edit-modules-content-in-frontend.html